# バッチからpowershellを実行しようとしたら　'powershell' は内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。　と出る

Tags: powershell, batch-file

https://www.shegolab.jp/entry/windows-conv-text-utf8
上記の「シフト JIS」 → 「標準 UTF-8」 変換をバッチとして用意し、使いたいバッチから「call sjis_utf8 %CSVFILEPATH%」　と呼び出すことで実行しようとしています。
単体であれば動くのですが、使いたい場所から呼び出すと
「'powershell' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。」
と出てしまいます。
バッチもpowershellも全く詳しくないので、どなたか教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 今の質問内容だと、どのような現象や問題が発生しているのか他の人が再現・調査するための情報が乏しくて助言や回答を得ることは難しいでしょう。どのようなディレクトリ・バッチファイル・データファイルが存在して、どのように(GUIでダブルクリック/コマンドプロンプトから/プログラムから)実行するのか、コマンドプロンプト等から手作業で実行した時との違いはあるのか、といったことを具体的な内容(バッチ等のソースやファイル名も含めて)で記述してみてください。その過程で自己解決することもあるでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 有りそうなのが、呼び出す側のバッチの中で直前等に`SET PATH=%~dp0`とかで追記(`SET PATH=%~dp0;%PATH%`)ではなく全て(あるいは中途半端に)書き変えてしまって元々の`PATH`の情報が失われているとか？ あと最近のこのサイトのQ&A記事の情報で、`PATH`のサイズに制限があるということで何かの操作でそれを超えてしまったとかは考えられませんか？